# How do I customize cursor in MRTK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm struggling to find documentation on cursor customization in MRTK. Consider a plain simple scenario - I want custom cursor when I focus on certain object in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into this official sample -- [EyeTracking](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/main/Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/EyeTracking), the visual effects of the “cursor” when a user is looking at an object is simply switching the state of the background object (enable/disable). You may refer to the sample to customize the visual effects.

Answer (score 0):

EyeTracking sample is not of much help, MRTK in fact does not provide available tools to customize cursor visuals. I see two options available:

1. Implement custom [BaseCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.basecursor?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0) similarly to how e.g. [AnimatedCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.animatedcursor?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0) is implemented and create your own context info class similarly to how [CursorContextInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.cursorcontextinfo?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0) is done. This is how MRTK modifies cursor when focusing on resize and scale handles.
2. Modify available pointer prefab, add your custom visuals into it and add a custom singleton script there. Use available focus on/off events on your content objects to modify cursor via singleton methods.